# C# : The while loops does not break, even the condition is available

Tags: c#

i'm writing a code to find the starting number of iterative sequence which include 100 numbers. Iterative means that : when you input a number n_input. if it is even n -> n/2,else  n -> 3*n +1 (odd). i use while loop to find this sequence. for example :

n_input =5. so the output is

5 -> 16->8->4->2->1.

Firstly, i create a method that has ability to calculate the iterative sequence with the starting number n_input. i use 2 while loop to find the starting number.

```
 static int calculate() // find the iterative consequence which has 100 number.
        {   int n_Input =2;
            int n = 0;
            int count = 0;
            while( count !=100)
            {
                count =0;
                n =n_Input;
                n_Input++;
                while (n != 1)
                {
                    if (n % 2 == 0)
                    {
                        n = n / 2;
                        Console.Write(n + "   ");
                        count++;
                    }
                    if (n % 2 == 1)
                    {
                        n = 3 * n + 1;
                        Console.Write(n + "   ");
                        count++;
                    }
                }
             }
        }
```

When the program runs, en=2 => the next number is 1. However, the `while (n != 1)` doesn't break, thus it makes a closed loop. Can you explain for me ? what happens with my method ? why doesn't the loop break ??

Comment: Did you try using the debugger?

Comment: A.k.a [Collatz conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture).

Comment: `n` starts at 2.  Then it enters the `if (n%2 == 0)` block and n is then divided by 2 so `n` now == 1.  Then the code enters the `if (n % 2 == 1)` block where `n` is changed to 4 in this line: `n = 3 * n + 1`.  The `while` loop repeats because `n != 1`.  Again it enters the `if (n%2 == 0)` block and `n` is changed to 2 and you are back where you started.  `n` alternates between 2 and 4 and is never equal to 1 so the loop never breaks.  If you had used the debugger, you would have seen this.  Also, your `Console.WriteLine` statements should have shown this too.

Comment: oh, i see it. i'm a stupid. thanks you lots of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a mathematical conjecture, the loop will end up being stuck in 4->2->1.

Answer (score 3):

This is mainly because `n` has to equal `1` in order to break out of the while loop.  `n` never equals `1`.  We will start off with the current value of `n`. The current value of `n` equals `n_input`, which happens to be `2`.  Once you get to the while loop, you are checking whether `n % 2 == 0` in the first if statement.  Of course it does.  So in the if statement, you change the value of `n` to `1`.  However changing the value of `n` also makes the next if statement true, because `1 % 2` does equal `1`.  So now you are changing the value of `n` again (`n = 3 * n + 1`) to `4`.  So even if the first if statement is true and you make `n` equal `1`, you are changing the value again in the next if statement to something other than 1, so the while loop becomes infinite.

So you would either need to add `continue` to the first if statement, like:

```
if (n % 2 == 0)
{
      n = n / 2;
      Console.Write(n + "   ");
      count++;
      continue;
}
```

Or:

```
if (n % 2 == 0)
{
    n = n / 2;
    Console.Write(n + "   ");
    count++;
}
else if (n % 2 == 1)
{
    n = 3 * n + 1;
    Console.Write(n + "   ");
    count++;
}
```

Or (suggested by @Kyle):

```
if (n % 2 == 0)
{
    n = n / 2;
}
else
{
    n = 3 * n + 1;
}
Console.Write(n + "   ");
count++;
```

And yes, you should change it to a `static void` method.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (n % 2 == 0)
{
      n = n / 2;
      Console.Write(n + "   ");
      count++;
      continue;
}
```

Comment: plus-one for being first... but the `if-else` solution is a little more elegant

Answer (score 2):

The problem is right here:

```
if (n % 2 == 0)
{
    n = n / 2;
    Console.Write(n + "   ");
    count++;
}
if (n % 2 == 1)
{
    n = 3 * n + 1;
    Console.Write(n + "   ");
    count++;
}
```

When `n == 2`, we enter the first if statement, `n` becomes 1, gets written to the console, then `count` is incremented.  Then we leave the first if statement and check the second if statement.  Since `n == 1` at this point, then `n % 2 == 1` and we enter the second if statement.  What you want here is an `else`.  `n % 2` can only ever be 0 or 1 (or sometimes -1 if `n < 0`), so each iteration of the loop should only enter exactly one of these branches:

```
if (n % 2 == 0)
{
    n = n / 2;
    Console.Write(n + "   ");
    count++;
}
else
{
    n = 3 * n + 1;
    Console.Write(n + "   ");
    count++;
}
```

Also, as an aside, notice that there's common code between both branches.  This code could be moved outside the `if-else`:

```
if (n % 2 == 0)
{
    n = n / 2;
}
else
{
    n = 3 * n + 1;
}
Console.Write(n + "   ");
count++;
```

Comment: thanks you so much. i see it :D. now i can finish pro.14 of Project Euler :D